# Unity3D (2D) Particle Outline possible like Where's My Water?

Tags: 2d, unity-game-engine, particle-system

I'm using Unity 5.4.f1 and I'm trying to make make a water similar to Where's My Water using particles...

The main issue I have is creating the white outline on particles:

[image: Where's My Water Imgage]

Does anyone have experience with this or perhaps a link that might point me in the right direction?  I have my particles blue and reacting nicely together in terms of movement, it's just the white outline that I can't seem to work out right now.

Thanks

Comment: My guess would be to look into the shader approach : such result can be achieved this way. However I can't tell you more since I not experienced in this field...

Comment: The shader approach?  I googled a while for "unity shader particles" and similar and didn't turn anything useful up, maybe you have a link I can steal? :)

Comment: Well you could try to look to [those assets](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/publisher/578), [this thread](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/wheres-my-water.283592/) or [this post](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/RobWare/20151026/257309/Optimising_PixelJunk_Shooter_and_giving_it_the_Ultimate_look.php) (all three found by googling _"unity 2d water particle shader"_)